# Не работает preview изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let $block = $('.block-variants').clone();

$('.click_to_add_block').click(function() {
  $(this).before($block.clone());
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

function readURL() {
  var $input = $(this);
  var $newinput = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.portimg ');
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      reset($newinput.next('.delbtn'), true);
      $newinput.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
      $newinput.after('<button type="button" class="delbtn removebtn">x</button>');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}
$(".fileUpload").change(readURL);
$(".choose-file").on('click', '.delbtn', function(e) {
  reset($(this));
});

function reset(elm, prserveFileName) {
  if (elm && elm.length > 0) {
    var $input = elm;
    $input.prev('.portimg').attr('src', '').hide();
    if (!prserveFileName) {
      $('input.fileUpload').val("");
    }
    elm.remove();
  }
}
```

```css
img.portimg {
  display: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-variants">
  <div class="choose-file">
    <div class=socialmediaside2>
      <input class=fileUpload name=profilepic[] type=file>
    </div>
    <div class=upload-demo>
      <div class=upload-demo-wrap><img class=portimg src=#></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="click_to_add_block" type="button">Добавить вариант</button>
```

При клонировании блока, а потом загрузке фото перестает работать preview - это первая проблема.

Вторая проблема заключается в том, что если делаю загрузку для нескольких файлов, отображается preview только для одной фото.

Помогите разобраться в этих двух проблемах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("change", ".fileUpload", readURL);
$(document).on('click', '.choose-file .delbtn', function (e) {
    reset($(this));
});
```